# Weird behavior counting lines from a file

Tags: c, algorithm, file, gcc

looking for a way to read arguments from a configuration file I found a nice way to do it but the thing is that something really weird happens when I try to count the lines.

This is the code:

```
FILE *file = fopen("config", "r");

char line[100];
int linenum = 0;
//int foo;  Uncomment and it starts to working, doesn't matter if you rename it.

while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL) {
    char option[4];
    char arg[100];

    if (line[linenum] == '#') 
        continue;
    linenum++;

    if (sscanf(line, "%s %s", option, arg) != 2)
        fprintf(stderr, "Syntax error, line %i\n", linenum);
```

The config file looks like this:

```
#config file
option1
option2
option3
```

So the result is:

```
Syntax error, line 1
Syntax error, line 0
Syntax error, line 0
```

But if I declare an int variable with any name before while loop it starts to working!

The result is:

```
Syntax error, line 1
Syntax error, line 2
Syntax error, line 3
```

What in the world is happening here? my mind is gonna blow, maybe it's something dumb but I don't see any reason for this.

Comment: Shouldn't be you're problem, but don't you want to check `line[0] == '#'` instead of `line[linenum]`?

Comment: You're right I just changed line[linenum] for line[0] thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you see strange behavior like this, you should start looking for memory overrun errors.  Typical symptoms include:

1. Code that works or stops working if you add or remove unused variables.
2. Variables that change for no apparent reason.
3. Code that sometimes runs normally and crashes other times, using the same input.
4. Code that produces different results between invocations, using the same input.

In this case, as the other answers point out, you have two potential memory-related errors:

The line `if (line[linenum] == '#') continue;`

should be `if (line[0] == '#') continue;`

Otherwise the index will be invalid when `linenum > 99`.

And the line `if (sscanf(line, "%s %s", option, arg) != 2){`

will overrun the `option` and `arg` variables if the input strings are too long.  (The error you're seeing occurs because the text (*e.g.* `option1`) is longer than 4 characters and overflows `option`.  You can fix this in several ways:

- Increase the size of `option`.  You'll need to know the maximum length of the input strings in order to choose an appropriate size.
- Limit the number of characters that are copied into `option`:
  `if (sscanf(line, "%3s %99s", option, arg) != 2){`
  This may cause unexpected output for long input strings, because `arg` will contain the remainder of the string in `option` if it's truncated.
- According to http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf you can use the `a` modifier to tell `sscanf` to allocate memory for the strings as it reads them:
  `char **str1, **str2;`
  `if (sscanf(line, "%as %as", &str1, &str2) != 2){`

Comment: Thanks a lot I really appreciate you took the time to check and explain me the errors in the code, very well explained btw.

Answer (score 3):

Your `option` array is too small (`char option[4]`) so `sscanf` overwrites other stuff. Undefined behavior.

Generally when weird things happen for no reason (like things "working" until you declare an unrelated variable) it's because of a memory issue. Since you mention `gcc` you might want to look into `valgrind`.

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot, I feel really dumb right now I've been fighting with this for hours, my understanding of how c works with memory it's kinda poor, I'm checking valgrind right now. Btw do you know a way to prevent sscanf from overwriting other things?

Comment: @gmol Use safe format specifiers. Increase the size of `option`. For example `char option[20]` and then in sscanf use `%19s` instead of `%s`.

Comment: Ok, that's what I'm gona do. Really appreciate your help thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this part at least:

```
if (line[linenum] == '#') continue;
  linenum++;
```

won't give the desired results since you're checking for a comment character at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sscanf(line, "%s %s", option, arg) != 2)
```

This overflows `option` array and will overwrite `linenum` object.